# Zoom scheduling support in Evolution

Tags: calendar, evolution, zoom

I have recently started using Zoom, and would love if there is anyway of scheduling meetings in zoom through the calendar in Evolution. Evolution is already linked to an Exchange server for the calendar etc. 
Has anyone been able to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can schedule the meeting in the zoom app and then choose "default mail client" for the calendar integration. If you have evolution set as your preferred application, then when you save the meeting, it will open a draft email.

The problem is that it does not default to a calendar item, but a mail item. So you have to go to "File->Convert to Meeting". This will make it a calendar item, but it does not correctly set the date, time, and duration. So you have to manually set them.

Alternatively, when you make the meeting in zoom you can select "Other Calendar" and save it as an ".ics" file which you can then import. But the import process is a menu with about 10 clicks, so not ideal. But it works.

Comment: Tank you for the answer. I'm aware of these workarounds, though as you clearly explain they are workarounds and not solutions as the require a lot of clicks and reduces zoom to only giving a link.